# App crashes when I use click listener on button in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have used ViewPager in MainActivity, which extends AppCompatActivity. When I remove setOnClickListener it doesn't crash but when I set click listener it crashes with given log.

Here is the log but still I don't understand why its happening

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2018-11-15 20:26:51.814 1654-1654/com.example.suraj.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.suraj.myapplication, PID: 1654
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:104)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:262)
        at com.example.suraj.myapplication.ThirdFragment.onClick(ThirdFragment.java:56)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I tried many times but still It's not working. My fragment code is as

```
package com.example.sdgh.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView ig3;
    View view;
    Context mContext;
    Button b;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       /* ViewGroup rootview3 = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_frag,container,false);
       ImageView ig3 = (ImageView)rootview3.findViewById(R.id.thirdimage);
      // Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(ig3);
       container.addView(rootview3);

       return rootview3;*/

       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_frag,container,false);
       ig3 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.thirdimage);
       b = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.thirdbutton);
       Picasso.get().load("https://cloudinary.com/images//da2fd17643796658bb733d1c848454590aa303cd/developeour-list.png").into(ig3);
       b.setOnClickListener(this);
       container.addView(view);

       return view;
    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.thirdbutton:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Third button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Onclicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    public static ThirdFragment newInstance(String text) {
        ThirdFragment f = new ThirdFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using 'mContext' but you are never initializing it. It's dropping the Nullpointer cause it is searching for a Context that currenly is Null.

Comment: Where are you initiating the mContext variable?

Comment: Even if I remove Toast.makeText(mContext,"Third button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); still it crashes

Comment: Is it the same error log or a different one when you remove the Toast line?

Comment: it will be different one. do you want me to post new logs here ?

Comment: so, show us your new error log

Comment: Can you post it? :)

Comment: why do u have container.addView(view);? show the error message you get WITHOUT the toast... because to answer your main question, its because of mContext. but now u have to adjust your question.

Comment: 18-11-15 20:56:56.780 614-630/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.android.systemui
    PID: 723
    Reason: executing service com.android.systemui/.keyguard.KeyguardService
    Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
    CPU usage from 38662ms to 0ms ago (2018-11-15 10:26:16.734 to 2018-11-15 10:26:55.396):
      1.5% 287/healthd: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
      1.6% 983/com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver: 0.9%

Comment: The above is with toast.maketext

Comment: Can you update the question with this new error log? Makes it easier to read :)

Comment: when I comment code of toast.make text its not crashing but log is as  --------- beginning of system
2018-11-15 21:06:14.852 266-295/? D/genymotion_audio: out_write: pcm_write() with out_frames=558 frame_size=4 returned -EPIPE

Comment: please remove commented code, and clean up the code it is confusing.

Comment: Well, there will be updates in the log; may be related to Android system, not to your app. So nothing to worry there if it's not crashing or generating any errors related to your app.

Comment: I think you can try out the edit suggested by @Onix and see if the toast is working without crashing the app

Comment: its working when I use getActivity() inside toast

Comment: Thanks blogger for your help. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You forgot init varible mContext.

```
Toast.makeText(mContext,"Third button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You can use getContext() or getActivity() like that:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Third button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Third button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Inside a fragment, getActivity() is preferred

Comment: Even if I remove Toast.makeText(mContext,"Third button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  still it crashes

Comment: Thanks onix your solution is working I used getAvctivity() and its working fine.